# What's the rationale behind preventing docker exec in stopped containers?

Tags: docker

I'd like to understand why docker prevents `exec` in a stopped container:

```
$ docker exec -it beautiful_banzai /bin/bash
Error response from daemon: Container 21663f6b7946(...) is not running
```

The filesystem of the stopped container is still available (I can `docker cp` inside it), so **what exactly prevents docker from just starting an arbitrary process in the context of the container**, without having the main process started?

Comment: Probably the fact that most of the runtime configuration is unavailable (network configuration (and thus also things like hostname resolution via DNS); special filesystem mounts like `/proc`, `/dev`, `/sys`, etc), so the command would not find the environment it expects.